# Could not load log4net assembly on IIS

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, log4net, iis-8

Getting error while running asp.net web app on IIS 8.'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'

I am generating stream (PDF format) from rpt file with Crystal Reports and sending as attachment in email. Its working fine for me at my local machine.
I am getting error while same code deploye on server.

I have changed Enable 32 bit Applications option to True,in IIS (as suggested by many users over the net), but its not works for me.Please help

Comment: Is the assembly log4net present?

Comment: yes , my project and class libraries  has reference of log4net v=1.2.9.0 and it present in bin folder

Comment: Try uninstalling CrystalReportRuntime 64 bit and install CrystalReportRuntime 32 bit